# EFCore+Razor Pages: nested foreach loop iterating over .included dataset returning zero results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am attempting to make a DotnetCore C# MVC Razor Page created by EF core show related table data and appear to either be having a problem with LINQ .include in my pagemodels OnGetAsync method or when trying to show the included contents in the Razor page.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide any more relevant information. I've only been doing EFCore/RazorPages/Mvc/C# for a couple months now, so please be kind!

Here is the `index.cshtml.cs` page where I include childtable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Appname.Models;

namespace Appname.Pages.Request
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Appname.Models.dbContext _context;

        public IndexModel(Appname.Models.dbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<ParentTable> ParentTable { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            ParentTable = await _context.ParentTable
                .Include(w => w.ChildTable)
                .ToListAsync(); //Output to an async list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `Index.cshtml` razor page where the nested `foreach` loop iterating over `Model.ParentTable[0].ChildTable` never has its conditions satisfied because `Model.ParentTable[0].ChildTable` has a count of zero when inspected during debugging and therefore no data for `ChildField1` or `ChildField2` is displayed:

```
@page
@model Appname.Pages.Request.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ParentTable[0].ParentField1)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ParentTable[0].ParentField2)
            </th>  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ParentTable)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentField1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentField2)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Child Field 1</th>
                            <th>Child Field 2</th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var relatedItem in Model.ParentTable[0].ChildTable)
                        {
                             <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => relatedItem.ChildField1)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => relatedItem.ChildField2)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ParentTableid">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.ParentTableid">Details</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the `ParentTable` model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Appname.Models
{
    public partial class ParentTable
    {
        [Key]
        public long ParentTableid { get; set; }
        public string ParentField1 { get; set; }
        public string ParentField2 { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ChildTable> ChildTable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

...And the `ChildTable` model, using non-standard ID naming conventions for EF Core because that's how the field was designed in the database this is being written to work with long ago (not sure if this is part of the problem or if I have my key fields set up wrong):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Appname.Models
{
    public partial class ChildTable
    {
        public long nonstandardidfield { get; set; }
        public string ChildField1 { get; set; }
        public string ChildField2 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("nonstandardidfield")]
        public ParentTable ParentTable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you are only every iterating over the ChildTable items of the first Model.

**Change this:**

```
@foreach (var relatedItem in Model.ParentTable[0].ChildTable)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => relatedItem.ChildField1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => relatedItem.ChildField2)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**To:**

```
@foreach (var relatedItem in item.ChildTable)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(ri => relatedItem.ChildField1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(ri => relatedItem.ChildField2)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the learning experience, this was exactly the issue was, and now I better understand how to access my related data! :D